Minimize all windows shortcut not updating on Sonoma
currently I'm struggling to update a shortcut that's occurring right now for the chrome browser. When I hit cmd + alt + m all chrome windows minimize to the task bar. This used to be a shortcut for an app called MeetingBar that let me join the upcoming meeting I have in my calendar. Now somehow that has magically changed to minimize all chrome windows. You can see here I have the following shortcut updated:

What's the best way to figure why this shortcut is still happening? It's quite annoying having to maximize all the chrome windows you've been hoarding.

To replace a key command you must use the exact wording on the menu.
A quick look at Chrome, Safari & Finder shows they all use 'Minimise All' [on a US system this may be Minimize All]
You just need to change the text in your control panel entry.
You'll also notice that if you add a new command to a menu that has Opt key alternates, it will then show both separately, e.g.


Wow what an obscure quirk with editing shortcuts in MacOS. This worked!
